# How to test the value of variable in overridden function before it is passed to the function of parent class

Tags: django, unit-testing, mocking, django-admin, overriding

I have overridden a function in my Django admin

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_some_results(self, request, input_string):
    input_string = input_string.encode('utf-8')
    end_of_string = 'some_value'
    input_string += end_of_string
    return super(MyAdmin, self).get_some_results(request, input_string)
```

I want to write a test that will check the input value for the function 'get_some_results' of a parent class ModelAdmin. In other words I want to check the value of 'input_string' after string:

```
input_string += end_of_string
```

In my test.py file I have a class

```
class TestAdminSearch(AppTestCase, MyAdmin):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TestAdminSearch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.url = '/admin/some_value/.../' # with this url get_some_results() is called

@mock.patch('django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_some_results')
def test_get_some_results(self, mock_some_result):
    search_string = 'some_string'
    expected_string = 'other_string'
    request_factory = RequestFactory()
    request = request_factory.get(self.url + search_string)
    result = mock_some_result.call_args_list
    self.assertEqual(result, (request, expected_string.encode('utf-8')))
```

But I get an AssertionError. It seems to me that mocked function is called with input_string but not with expected_string. But after the line

```
input_string += end_of_string
```

input string is equal to expected_string.

Do you have an idea of what I'm doing wrong or how else can I check the value of input_string before the line?

```
return super(MyAdmin, self).get_some_results(request, input_string)
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This would be clearer if you used the actual method names. It seems likely you're patching in the wrong place (you should patch your module, not Django's). But your approach is fundamentally wrong: the point of unit tests is that you test your method *as a unit*, without digging into the implementation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I might be mistaken, but I'm trying to test my method, I would like to check the work of part of the function that is in my class. I want to know the value of the variable that is passed to Django Admin class, and it seems to me that I need to patch 'django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_some_results' and to check what it was called with (after work of function of my class)

Comment: No. Read this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch